# Get option value and text using jQuery of ESelect2 extensions in YII

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jquery-select2

Hello Friends this is my code

```
$this->widgets('ext.select.ESelect2', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'state',
    'data' => $data,
    'htmloptions'=>array(
     'multiple'=>'multiple',
      ),
    'options' =>array(
        'placeholder' => 'Select a state ...',
        'allowClear'=> true,
         ), 
    ));
```

How can i get option value and text in jquery. I want to need the value of selected options.
Please suggest and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of an input using their class or id of the input try this one:

```
$('#id_select_input').change(function() {
   var selected  = $(this).val(); 
   var textValue = $this.text();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

```
$this->widgets('ext.select.ESelect2', array(
'id'=>'id_select_input',
'model' => $model,
'attribute' => 'state',
'data' => $data,
'htmloptions'=>array(
 'multiple'=>'multiple',
  ),
'options' =>array(
    'placeholder' => 'Select a state ...',
    'allowClear'=> true,
     ), 
));
```

Comment: it returns a blank array when i console it.

Comment: does your select input has id?

Comment: yes my select have id. that is s2id_state. and its a searchable drop-down when i add additional id than its convert into default drop-down.

Comment: how about using its class then change the selector to $('.class_of_select').